# Using a URDF in Gazebo clarification

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running on an Ubuntu machine, with ROS Kinetic Kame, and was starting in on this tutorial (see title)
http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20a%20URDF%20in%20Gazebo

I get the following error:

```
[gazebo.launch] is neither a launch file in package [urdf_sim_tutorial] nor is [urdf_sim_tutorial] a launch file name
```

At the terminal prompt, I entered:

```
user@UBU01-LC:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
```

Followed by:

```
user@UBU01-LC:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch urdf_sim_tutorial gazebo.launch
```

My thoughts: perhaps I don't have files in the right directories, or I'm trying to run from the wrong directory

Any suggestions or advice is appreciated.
Thanks!
Ryan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281197/using-a-urdf-in-gazebo-clarification/) by [rtthomps](https://answers.ros.org/users/33466/rtthomps/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you made sure to `source` the `devel/setup.bash` between invoking `catkin_make` and calling `roslaunch`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1